# keeping last record among group of records with common fields (awk)

Tags: bash, shell, awk

INPUT FILE :

```
0,,M00,100,,SEK,20190411T10:02:12+0530,20190425T23:59:59+0530,,vsuser,,5774126050,12345685865,,,test,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,C
0,,M00,100,,SEK,20190411T10:02:12+0530,20190425T23:59:59+0530,20190411T10:02:12+0530,,vsuser,5774126050,12345685865,,,test,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,H
5,,M00,100,,SEK,20190411T10:02:12+0530,20190425T23:59:59+0530,20190411T15:42:17+0530,,vsuser,5774126050,12345685865,,,test,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,H
0,,M00,100,,SEK,20190411T10:02:12+0530,20190425T23:59:59+0530,20190411T15:42:37+0530,,vsuser,5774126050,12345685865,,,test,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,H
0,,M00,100,,SEK,20190411T10:03:16+0530,20190425T23:59:59+0530,,vsuser,,7318713283,12345729902,,,test,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,C
0,,M00,100,,SEK,20190411T10:03:16+0530,20190425T23:59:59+0530,20190410T10:03:16+0530,,vsuser,7318713283,12345729902,,,test,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,H
```

OUTPUT DESIRED :

```
0,,M00,100,,SEK,20190411T10:02:12+0530,20190425T23:59:59+0530,20190411T15:42:37+0530,,vsuser,5774126050,12345685865,,,test,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,H
0,,M00,100,,SEK,20190411T10:03:16+0530,20190425T23:59:59+0530,20190410T10:03:16+0530,,vsuser,7318713283,12345729902,,,test,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,H
```

Select the row with common value of 13th column .

Comment: Store the lines in an array whose keys are `$13`. At the end, print the elements of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Below `awk` might help :

```
awk -F, '{found[$13]=$0}END{for(i in found){print found[i]}}' file
```

**Output**

```
0,,M00,100,,SEK,20190411T10:02:12+0530,20190425T23:59:59+0530,20190411T15:42:37+0530,,vsuser,5774126050,12345685865,,,test,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,H
0,,M00,100,,SEK,20190411T10:03:16+0530,20190425T23:59:59+0530,20190410T10:03:16+0530,,vsuser,7318713283,12345729902,,,test,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,H
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ tac file | awk -F, '!seen[$13]++' | tac
0,,M00,100,,SEK,20190411T10:02:12+0530,20190425T23:59:59+0530,20190411T15:42:37+0530,,vsuser,5774126050,12345685865,,,test,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,H
0,,M00,100,,SEK,20190411T10:03:16+0530,20190425T23:59:59+0530,20190410T10:03:16+0530,,vsuser,7318713283,12345729902,,,test,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,H
```